# ERR_CONNECTION_RESET with nginx reverse proxy and gunicorn

Tags: python, nginx

I have a web application written with flask that run perfectly fine with most user. However, some user with specific mobile phone operators (SFR and Bouygues Télécom, french mobile phone operators) can't access the web app.

I found out that they get a ERR_CONNECTION_RESET on firefox mobile. I noticed this error in nginx log `2021/08/17 19:16:58 [crit] 324713#324713: *110940 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:141CF06C:SSL routines:tls_parse_ctos_key_share:bad key share) while SSL handshaking, client: *.*.*.*, server: 0.0.0.0:443`  but it doesn't seem relevant : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65854933/nginx-ssl-error141cf06cssl-routinestls-parse-ctos-key-sharebad-key-share

The web app use nginx and gunicorn.

Here is nginx config file :

```
server {
    if ($host = www.domain.fr) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = domain.fr) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    # listen on port 80 (http)
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.fr www.domain.fr;
    location / {
        # redirect any requests to the same URL but on https
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}
server {
    # listen on port 443 (https)
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name domain.fr domain.fr;

    # write access and error logs to /var/log
    access_log /var/log/web_app_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/web_app_error.log;

    location / {
    if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        #
        # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
        #
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
        #
        # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
        #
        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
        add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
        add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
        return 204;
    }
    if ($request_method = 'POST') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
    }
    if ($request_method = 'GET') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
    }
    # forward application requests to the gunicorn server
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location /static {
        # handle static files directly, without forwarding to the application
        alias /home/barman/web-app/app/static;
        expires 30d;
    }
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.fr/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.fr/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

Gunicorn is run by supervisorctl :

```
[program:web_app]
command=/home/barman/web-app/venv/bin/gunicorn -b localhost:8000 -w 4 web_app:app
directory=/home/barman/web-app
user=barman
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stopasgroup=true
killasgroup=true
```

This issue is very weird so do you have any how to fix it ? Thank you

Comment: Minor comment but shouldn't `server_name domain.fr domain.fr;` be `server_name domain.fr www.domain.fr;`?

Comment: Yes I just a misspelled when I hid the real domain